# Bootstrap 4 Alpha - Collapse - Uncaught Error

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

So I am recently developing a website, and rather than using a navbar which drops from desktop to mobile, I am using two different navbars.

With the mobile navbar, it is a fixed navbar with a button to toggle using the collapse feature the display of the content below.

This is the error:

```
    Uncaught Error: Collapse is transitioning
    at l.show (bootstrap.min.js:6)
    at l.toggle (bootstrap.min.js:6)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (bootstrap.min.js:6)
    at Function.each (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2)
    at r.fn.init.each (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2)
    at r.fn.init.l._jQueryInterface [as collapse] (bootstrap.min.js:6)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (bootstrap.min.js:6)
    at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:3)
    at HTMLDocument.q.handle (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:3)
l.show @ bootstrap.min.js:6
l.toggle @ bootstrap.min.js:6
(anonymous) @ bootstrap.min.js:6
each @ jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2
each @ jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2
l._jQueryInterface @ bootstrap.min.js:6
(anonymous) @ bootstrap.min.js:6
dispatch @ jquery-3.1.1.min.js:3
q.handle @ jquery-3.1.1.min.js:3
```

The collapse feature of the navbar works fine when there is no other content on the page, but as soon as content is put on the page it stops working and throws up that error.

If anyone has any ideas it would be greatly appericiated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [bootstraps 4 Error: Collapse is transitioning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42453332/bootstraps-4-error-collapse-is-transitioning)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I answered here: [bootstraps 4 Error: Collapse is transitioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42453332/bootstraps-4-error-collapse-is-transitioning)

There is an error on the [Bootstrap](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap) `v4.0.0-alpha.6` version with the transitioning that will be solved on the next release.

See [issue 22256](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/22256) and [issue 21743](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/21743) links for more information.

For while, you can use workarounds like the *@Nayana_Das* example on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42453332/bootstraps-4-error-collapse-is-transitioning).