# Bootstrap 4 - collapseMenu collapse

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap 4.0.0-alpha.6 css and bootstrap 4.0.0-alpha.6 js.  Seems I am having an issue where bootstrap is only adding *aria-expanded* to the first item in my list but not the other, which seems odd.
**HTML Code:**

```
<div class="left-panel">
    <div>
        <button data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".collapseMenu">open/close</button>
    </div>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>Icon <span class="collapseMenu collapse">Contact</span></li>
            <li>Icon <span class="collapseMenu collapse">Home</span></li>

        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="main">
    <p>
        Main content...
    </p>
</div>
```

The **html output** (F12) shows:

```
<span class="collapseMenu collapse" aria-expanded="false">Contact</span>
<span class="collapseMenu collapse">Home</span>
```

Where the 2nd item (*Home*) doesn't include the **aria-expanded="false"**.  If I try to expand the menu, the first one works (*Contact*) expands as expected, but the *Home* fails to expand.

I've included a working example
https://www.codeply.com/go/wLBLDWbMmf

Comment: Looks to be a known BS4 bug: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42453332/bootstraps-4-error-collapse-is-transitioning

Comment: Thanks for the response.  At this point, I can only assume that it's bug related.  I knew there were issues around using _tooltip_ within bootstrap 4.0.0-alpha.6 but did not realize other bug issues as simple as this one still did.